# NodeName of TextNode is not displaying correctly in JAVA xml parsing

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am parsing XML document in a JavaBean using org.w3c.dom api.

If a Node is an ElementNode then the method node.getNodeName() returns the tagname of the node.

But if i use it on the childnode which has text content, it does not return the tagname. But it returns the nodeType such as #TextNode or #CDATA. But I want to get the TagName of the ChildNode also. 
I have tried

```
node.getNodeName();
node.getNodeValue();
node.getTextContent();
```

None of above three methods return the tagname of the child node which has Textcontent.
What is the correct method?

Answer (score 1):

If the node type is coming back as CDATA or TextNode, then the node you're looking at *is* the text data - it's not the element *containing* the text data. Therefore that node *has* no tag name - it's not a tag. You should ask it for its parent node (which *will* be an element) and find the name of that.

If that doesn't help, please post some sample code (ideally a short but *complete* console app we can copy, paste, compile and run), the XML you're running it with, the expected output and the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the xml document and your code. Your actually looking at a *Text* Node or a *CDATA-section* but not at an *Element*.

You can check this by either doing a

```
if (childnode.getType != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
  System.out.println("Ooops, navigation error, need to turn around");
}
```

or by adding some debug code for a moment

```
System.out.println(childnode.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(childnode.getParentNode().getNodeName());
```